# HAproxy and nginx RTMP

Tags: nginx, centos, reverse-proxy, haproxy, rtmp

I am trying to use HAproxy in front of an RTMP nginx server.

It does connect but it does not play the video.

I have 2 servers: one **with nginx using RTMP** and another one **with HAproxy**.

This is the **HAproxy** config:

```
listen rtmp :1935
mode tcp
 balance roundrobin
server s1 rtmp_server_ip:1935 check
```

I have also tried to set it to port 1936.

This is the **nginx RTMP** config:

```
rtmp
 {
    server
     {
        listen 1935;
        listen 1936 proxy_protocol;

        notify_method get;
        on_play http://127.0.0.1/vod_handler;
        application vod
        {
                play /path_to_videos/uploads/;
        }
}
   }
```

This is how the setup should be:

**web >> haproxy >> nginx RTMP**

Comment: What do your logs say? What error messages are you getting? Detail, we need details!!

Comment: no error logs that the weird thing..

Comment: Well, put in the error log lines in your config. Then you will get some :)

Comment: i mean i have fixed the errors that was showing in logs.. i was getting error bad time and bad ip